# Move a checked checkbox from one list to another using jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, checkbox, move

I am trying to move checked items between lists when clicking a link:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    return !$('#select1 li:checked').appendTo('#select2');
});
$('#remove').click(function() {
    return !$('#select2 li:checked').appendTo('#select1');
});


<ul id="select1">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" />Checkbox 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_1" />Checkbox 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_2" />Checkbox 3</label>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul id="select2">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup2" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup2_0" />Checkbox 4</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup2" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup2_1" />Checkbox 5</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup2" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup2_2" />Checkbox 6</label>
    </li>
</ul>

<a href="#" id="add">add</a>
<a href="#" id="remove">remove</a>
```

Currently if I hit the add or remove links it just moves one of the entire lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect. The `:checked` selector looks for input elements that are checked (so checkboxes or radio buttons), but you're trying to find `<li>` elements that are checked (something that can't happen).

What you instead need to do is find the `:checked` elements *inside* the `<li>` elements, then get references to their containing `<li>` elements, and then move them. The code to do that would look like this:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    return !$('#select1 li :checked').closest('li').appendTo('#select2');
});
$('#remove').click(function() {
    return !$('#select2 li :checked').closest('li').appendTo('#select1');
});
```

If you want to take a look at [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/EEhbQ/).